# ngOnChanges gets executed only once

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I have used ngonchange in my child component as shown below. But i see that it is getting only executed once. So basically i have a dropdown in my child component so when i change something in my dropdown i want the ngonchange to be executed, which is happening only once. The second time i change the item then ngonchange is not getting executed.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
  console.info(changes.test);
  if(this.test!=null){
    console.info(this.test);
    this.currentSnapshotPeriod = this.snapshotPeriods.filter(x => x.periodName === this.test)[0];
 this.onCurrentSnapshotPeriodChange();
 changes.SimpleChanges.currentValue = undefined;
  }
}
```

Parent HTML :

```
<app-snapshot-period-dropdown
                       [test]=input
                         (change)="abc($event)"
                        >
                    </app-snapshot-period-dropdown>
```

Child HTML :

```
<select
      id="currentPeriodDropDown"
      (change)="onCurrentSnapshotPeriodChange()"
      [(ngModel)]="currentSnapshotPeriod"
      class="form-control form-control-sm mr-1 form-control-sm-ipad"
    >
      <option [ngValue]="period" *ngFor="let period of snapshotPeriods"
        >{{ period?.periodName }}
      </option>
    </select>
```

Comment: It would be better if you share stackblitz

Comment: @JoelJoseph Actually what i have done is that i have created abc function and that function calls onCurrentSnapshotPeriodChange($event)

Comment: @taashibhulani ya i saw that

Comment: @JoelJoseph so that should be fine right?

Comment: @taashibhulani no  , you should be binding `(change)="ngOnChanges($event)` also please post the definition of `onCurrentSnapshotPeriodChange()`

Comment: @JoelJoseph ngOnChanges only gets triggered when the @Input() gets changed from the parent component, not if you change it in you child component. This was the mistake that i had made. I forgot to clear the input. Now it is working thanks

Answer (score 0):

ngOnChanges only gets triggered when the @Input() gets changed from the parent component, not if you change it in you child component. this was the mistake i was doing